# What's the best way to render raw HTML and print it (to a printer) from the command-line?

Tags: linux, printing, command-line-interface

Put another way, here's my web page:

```
/usr/bin/curl --cookie ~/.cookies 'http://somewhere.com'
```

And I'm looking for a command that goes something like

```
/usr/bin/curl --cookie ~/.cookies 'http://somewhere.com' | render_raw_html_to_image | lpr
```

Comment: i.e. I'm trying to print the actual, rendered web page.  Not the source code.  Any browser rendering will do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use firefox with the [Command Line Print](http://torisugari.googlepages.com/commandlineprint2) extension.

```
firefox -print http://www.example.com/index.html
firefox -print http://www.example.com/index.html -printmode pdf -printfile ../foo.pdf
firefox -print http://www.example.com/index.html -printmode PNG
firefox -print http://www.example.com/index.html -printdelay 10
```

[source](http://torisugari.googlepages.com/commandlineprint2)

Comment: this appears to be deprecated :(

Answer (score 4):

You could try using [**wkhtmltopdf**](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/), which uses the webkit engine to render an HTML page into a PDF file. Then you can print the PDF.

Answer (score 0):

http://htmldoc.org/ may help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use links with the dump switch:

```
links www.google.com -dump > formatedOutput.txt
```

And the same with lynx:

```
lynx www.google.com -dump > formatedOutput.txt
```

And yet again, the same with w3m:

```
w3m www.google.com -dump > formatedOutput.txt
```

Comment: Oh, missed the raw_image image part, it was cut off by the scroll bar in my browser :-)